# Move or copy without overwrite and check success

Tags: cp, mv

**Problem:**
I'm looking for a way to rename or copy a file without overwriting the destination file, if it exists, and then check the success of the move or copy operation. I'm seeking a method that will work with the BSD versions of mv/cp installed on MacOS/Unix, and also the GNU coreutils versions I have on Linux.

**Solution attempt:**
In all versions of mv/cp, I can prevent overwriting the destination file with the `-n` flag:

```
mv -n file1 file2
cp -n file1 file2
```

Similar questions suggest testing the success of mv and cp using the exit status, which is 0 if successful and >0 if an error occurred. However, for both versions of mv/cp, the exit code is 0 when the destination file already exists and the `-n` flag is used.

The only other option I can think of is to also use the `-v` flag, and look at the output of the command:

```
mv -nv file1 file2
cp -nv file1 file2
```

However, the GNU and BSD versions of mv/cp behave differently when the `-nv` flags are used and file2 already exists: the GNU versions of mv/cp return nothing, whereas the BSD versions return `file2 not overwritten`.

Our previous method was to check whether the destination file exists first, then do the mv/cp operation. Believe it or not, this caused problems because the destination file would sometimes get created by another process between the time that the check was performed and the mv/cp operation was executed.

Is there a way to accomplish this task that works with both BSD and GNU versions of mv/cp?

Alternatively, is there are way to do this using Python 2? I couldn't find a way to do this using os.rename()

Answer (score 4):

If you have `bash` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828544/atomic-create-file-if-not-exists-from-bash-script

> ```
> set -o noclobber
> { > file ; } &> /dev/null
> ```
>
> This command creates a file named file if there's no existent file
>   named file. If there's a file named file, then do nothing (but return
>   a non-zero return code).

I.e. create an empty file first using this technique.  If that succeeds, you can then overwrite the empty file.

Similarly for python.  Use `os.open()` to create an empty file, making sure to include `O_EXCL` in the flags.  ("For a description of the flag and mode values, see the C run-time documentation."  See [POSIX standard](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) / [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)).

---

The bash technique is using `O_EXCL` behind the scenes.  There is also [`RENAME_NOREPLACE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), but it is a relatively recent addition in Linux, and I do not think it is present on OS X.

Comment: I guess you meant do something like `os.open("file", os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXCL)` ?

Comment: I have edited and linked to reference documentation for os.open().  I am being lazy here and just pointing you towards `O_EXCL`, didn't feel like checking through all the implications (in two different languages).  If you want to accept (and/or write) an answer that provides more detail, that's fine.

Comment: @srcerer the question as written is still slightly ambiguous to me, because I'm not certain that `bash` is not as conveniently available for whichever OS X setups you are targeting... Sorry I don't know what exactly to suggest to make the question unambiguous to me, but it's why I originally posted as a comment, saying *if* `bash` was available.  If you had only needed Linux instructions I think there would be nothing to stop me upvoting; I like thinking about the general topic.

Comment: @srcerer it doesn't explicitly say which shell you're using to script mv / cp.  General Linux, I could assume `bash` is available. I was aiming for a little collaboration... actually looks like OS X provides `bash`, it's general BSD that you can't rely on it being there, although looking at the versions I am not sure whether it is a good plan on OS X... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82244/bash-in-linux-v-s-mac-os

Answer (score 2):

If the files are on the same filesystem, then you can create a [hardlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardlink).

```
ln SRC DEST
```

If that succeeds, you can then remove the source file.

```
rm SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD does indeed return failure if `cp -n` is asked to overwrite a file:

```
$ rm -f foo.*
$ date > foo.1
$ date > foo.2
$ # this should fail
$ cp -n foo.1 foo.2 || echo fail
fail
$ rm foo.2
$ # this should succeed
$ cp -n foo.1 foo.2 || echo fail
$ exit
```

You are correct when you state that FreeBSD's `mv` returns success even when the destination exists:

```
$ rm -f foo.*
$ date > foo.1
$ date > foo.2
$ # this should fail
$ mv -n foo.1 foo.2 || echo fail
$ exit
```

One workaround is to `&&` the `mv` result code with `[ ! -f src-file ]`, as in:

```
$ rm -f foo.*
$ date > foo.1
$ date > foo.2
$ # this should fail
$ ( mv -n foo.1 foo.2 && [ ! -f foo.1 ] ) || echo fail
fail
$ rm foo.2
$ # this should succeed
$ ( mv -n foo.1 foo.2 && [ ! -f foo.1 ] ) || echo fail
$ exit
```

Under GNU, neither utility performs the way you would like.  The same workaround for `mv` works for me on Ubuntu, so that leaves GNU `cp` as as the one remaining problem case.

Just as an aside, I hear your comment about the race condition with testing for the destination file before calling `cp`, but it strikes me that the same race condition would be present even if `cp` did the right thing.  The window of opportunity might be smaller, but my intuition is that it would still be there.  IANAE, however.

Since the workaround for `mv` works on both platforms, perhaps this workaround will suffice:

```
$ rm -f foo.*
$ date > foo.1
$ date > foo.2
$ # this should fail
$ ( cp -n foo.1 TEMPFILE && mv -n TEMPFILE foo.2 && [ ! -f TEMPFILE ] ) || echo fail
fail
$ rm -f TEMPFILE
$ rm foo.2
$ # this should succeed
$ ( cp -n foo.1 TEMPFILE && mv -n TEMPFILE foo.2 && [ ! -f TEMPFILE ] ) || echo fail
$ rm -f TEMPFILE
$ exit
```